# Touch pad turns off when booting Ubuntu?

Tags: touchpad

I'm trying to install Ubuntu, but when it boots up, my touch pad gets disabled so I can't select what I want on the setup. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Can you use the arrow keys to select? Linux does not support every touch pad driver since many manufacturers don't bother making them. And if a linux driver exists, there are ways to inject your specific driver into the Ubuntu install so it would work but I have never done that before

Comment: I can, but it's very limited. Like, for example, I want to use the live version instead of fully installing it, but I can't seem to get the keyboard to get over to choose that option.

Comment: Cool. Can you tell us information about your laptop, touchpad model, and Ubuntu version? :)